# VueJS 3 Composition API. Can anyone explain why this will not work?

Tags: vuejs3

I'm loading a simple JSON file, assigning it to a reactive variable, and displaying it in the template. However, it only works partly.

`{{ people }}`, `{{ people.People }}`, and in a `people.People` in a `v-for` loop work as expected,
but accessing the `people.People[0].FullName` fails. But why? Any insight is appreciated.

Here is my .json

```
{
    "People": [
        {
            "FullName": "The Json"
        }, {
            "FullName": "The Jetsons"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the `component.vue` code

````
<template>
<h1>Test</h1>
<div>
    <p>{{ people }}</p> <!-- Works and displays: { "People": [ { "FullName": "The Json" }, { "FullName": "The Jetsons" } ] } -->
    <p>{{ people.People }}</p> <!-- Works and displays: [ { "FullName": "The Json" }, { "FullName": "The Jetsons" } ] -->
    <p>{{ people.People[0].FullName }}</p> FAILS - Uncaught TypeError: $setup.people.People is undefined
    <p v-for="(item, idx) in people.People" :key="idx">
        {{ item.FullName }} <!-- Works as expected -->
    </p>
</div>

</template>

<script>

import { ref } from 'vue'

    export default {
        name: "Test",
        setup() {

            const people = ref({});

            fetch('http://localhost:3000/data/people.json')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => people.value = data);

                return {
                    people
                }
            }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>```


Thanks
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At "setup time" before your json is loaded :
`people = {}`, so `people.People[Ø]` raises an error cause `people.People` is not defined at this moment

In your exemple
`{{ people }}` and `{{ people.People }}` display something cause it's reactive and you just don't have time to see it before the json is loaded

There is several ways to manage this. ere is two of them

Add an if

`<p v-if="people.People">{{ people.People[0].FullName }}</p>`

Init with default walues

```
const people = ref({
    People: []
});
```

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for your answer. Is there a way to make everything reactive, including access to ```people.People[0]```, like it is when one uses ```import people from 'path/people.json'```?

Comment: It is reative. I added some some solutions in my post